# What is the Font type of "pocket edition" text in Minecraft Pocket Edition logo?

Tags: font-identification, logo

Does someone know the font type of the text "pocket edition" in the Minecraft Pocket Edition logo pictured here?

[image: MINECRAFT POCKET EDITION LOGO]

Comment: My inclination is that it's hand drawn to keep the 8-bit pixel feel at the distortion.

Comment: If you have a Twitter account, it may be work sending something to [Junkboy](https://twitter.com/jnkboy), who I believe made it. He makes the majority of the graphics for Mojang – Minecraft in particular – so he's the most likely candidate. Other than that, all I can say is that it's some kind of heavy party-slab party-sans typeface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the font used in the "POCKET EDITION" is [AddLGBitmap09](http://www.dafont.com/addlgbitmap09.font?text=POCKET%20EDITION) :

[image]

On this picture it can be clearly seen that the letters have "bits" -

[image]